# How to add drop down list for timezone using python-TZ at user registration page using UserCreationForm class

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I want to add a Drop down list showing common timezone using PYtZ package at the time of user registration page. To register an user i am using UserCreationForm class. Code as follow:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"))

    def clean_email2(self):
        email2 = self.cleaned_data['email2']
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email2)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email2
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Account with this e-mail address already exists."))

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email2"]
        user.is_active = False
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

I am getting the list of all common timezone using following command:

```
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> import pytz
>>> print(pytz.common_timezones)
```

it prints:
http://pastebin.com/RHdie16M

I am also aware of the choices fields but to use that is not a good idea. What should i do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use a choicefield as such:

```
timezone = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in pytz.common_timezones])
```

Comment: everything is fine but this timezone is not adding into database. What should i do?

Comment: Your question title is "how to add a dropdown list ...". Anyway, here's a link to [Django documentation about Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)

Comment: Yeh! i read that :)
Now i am facing another problem i.e i have done it by adding a timezone in UserProfile model and the coloum is added to the table but i am not able to find out any way to connect it with timezone (above you defined) field in usercreation form

Comment: Can you present your problem nicely in another topic please ? It's too small in comments ... thanks !